# How to check instring for alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following dataset:

```
## IDENTIFIER | Column1        | column 2 ##          
IDENT1        | 150, oven, 450 | 159,246,849
```

I need to check whether or not one of the comma separated values is an alphanumeric value.
How can I do this?

Comment: In this example, all the comma-separated values are alphanumeric.  And, you have two columns.  And, you shouldn't store multiple values in a string column anyway.

Comment: Parse the column contents and check if each element is a number. I don't know if a stored procedure can do this. I use Access and VBA and would write a custom function.

Comment: I can't test this because I don't have an oracle system, but I would write a query twice.. using logic you can lookup online related to regexp_substr('*', '[^,]+', 1, level) from dual connect by regexp_substr('*', '[^,]+', 1, level).  One version should identify ANY character in regex, the other should identify only alphanumeric. These 2 queries can be joined together using an outer join to identify ones that are in the "any" query and ones that are NOT in the alphanumeric query. Oh yeah, and then repeat the entire process for the 2nd column. Not fun, but thats my only idea to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one option; read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, col1, col2) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 1, '150,oven,450', '159,246,849' from dual union all  --> valid
  5     select 2, 'abc,123'     , 'def,1#5,331' from dual            --> col2 invalid
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    -- split comma-separated values into rows, check every part of it. If it is not alphanumeric, return 1
  9    (select id,
 10      col1,
 11      col2,
 12      case when not regexp_like(regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, a.column_value), '^[[:alnum:]]+$') then 1
 13           else 0
 14      end val1,
 15      --
 16      case when not regexp_like(regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, b.column_value), '^[[:alnum:]]+$') then 1
 17           else 0
 18      end val2
 19     from test cross join
 20       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 21                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, ',') + 1
 22                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) a
 23            cross join
 24       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 25                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, ',') + 1
 26                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) b
 27    )
 28  -- final query; if all parts of the column are alphanumerics, summary is 0 so it is valid.
 29  -- Otherwise, summary is larger than 0 and is invalid
 30  select id,
 31    col1,
 32    col2,
 33    case when sum(val1) > 0 then 'invalid' else 'valid' end valid_col1,
 34    case when sum(val2) > 0 then 'invalid' else 'valid' end valid_col2
 35  from temp
 36  group by id, col1, col2
 37  order by id;

        ID COL1         COL2        VALID_COL1 VALID_COL2
---------- ------------ ----------- ---------- ----------
         1 150,oven,450 159,246,849 valid      valid
         2 abc,123      def,1#5,331 valid      invalid

SQL>
```